# Modify JQuery Animate To Function In Loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use Jquery to fade an element's background color out from red each time certain criteria is met in a loop.  The problem is that the code below works by itself, but when placed in a loop it doesn't ever go to red; I'm thinking multiple instances under animate fire at the same time and it crashes.  Short of putting a system in place to detect when the function below is complete before continuing the loop, is there a way to ensure that it fires each time it's called from the beginning without crashing?

```
        $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 2000, function() {
            $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 2000);
        });
```

Comment: Where is your loop code?

Comment: Shouldn't matter...  Just picture a generic for loop if it helps?   The issue is that 2000 ms delay not running out before the line is getting called again.  I'm trying to find a better way to do that fade without having to keep track of the operation finishing before going to the next step.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really using a loop (`for`, `while`)? If so, executing this many times *instantly* on `#output` won't have any interest...

If, however, you want that function to repeat itself, you could use recursion. Just put that code inside a function, and as a callback, call it again:

```
function myFunction(){
    $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 2000, function() {
        $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 2000, myFunction);
    });
}

myFunction();
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

**Edit**

To allow the animation to complete before being executed again, you can to this:

```
var isAnimating = false;

function myFunction(){
    if(isAnimating) return false;
    isAnimating = true;
    $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 2000, function() {
        $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 2000, function(){
            isAnimating = false;
        });
    });
}

someSortOfLoop(myFunction);
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: It is similar to a while, but it's based on an outside source (think streaming data from an ajax call).  Realistically it get's called once a second, but animate doesn't have a chance to finish before getting called again.  Do you think the only option would be to rework the logic so that it waits for completion?    My previous solution was an animated background .gif that faded out, but IE's buggy handling of gif transparencies forced me to try to implement a jquery alternative...

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I was thinking...  Without detecting animate's completion, I guess there aren't other options.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to put a checker that the color has turned in to red:

```
        $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 2000, function() {
            if ($('#outputdiv').is(':animated')) 
               $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 2000);
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you do it in this way :         $('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 2000);
$('#outputdiv').animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 2000);